# VAT changes - how to change VAT and then round price up

Tags: mysql, rounding

With the UK VAT rate due to change in the New Year, several clients will need to update their sites to the new VAT rate. As prices are all stored in a MySQL table (excluding VAT), changing the actual VAT rate is a simple flag in the backend of most sites, but this leaves 'ugly' prices £10.87, rather than £10.99.

I'd like to run a query against the prices to alter the prices so that all of the new prices (when the new VAT rate is added) are 'nice' prices rather than ugly ones.

For instance:

Current Price (ex VAT): £8.50

Current Price (VAT @ 17.5%): £9.99

New Price (VAT @ 20%): £10.20

Desired Price (VAT @ 20%): £10.99

Comment: Ouch for the consumer - not only an additional 2.5% tax but also a 7% increase just to make the number look nice ;)

Comment: Surely the 'nice' price at 20% VAT would still be "£9.99". Using the VAT increase to make an additional 79p profit (a 7.75% price rise) is neither nice nor likely to go unnoticed among existing customers. Not a developer response but we're consumers too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you'd always like prices with .99, it should be pretty easy to do:

```
update articles set price = round((ceil(8.50 * 1.2) - 0.01) / 1.2, 2);
```

proof:

```
mysql> select round((ceil(8.50 * 1.2) - 0.01) / 1.2, 2) as price;
+-------+
| price |
+-------+
|  9.16 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

in favor of competitive prices you could also consider [floor(x)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) instead of [ceil(x)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) though ;)

Comment: You have to divide by 1.2 again because in the database the prices are stored excluding tax.

Comment: @andre you're right of course. i was already fixing it while you were commenting.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks very much. I'll give this a go (on Thursday) and confirm solved then.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE products SET price = (CEIL(price*1.20)-0.01)/1.20 WHERE product_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it's dishonest to your customers to try and disguise a price rise as a VAT increase, you could use something like CEIL (which rounds a decimal up to the nearest integer), then - 0.01.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that that is the way it looks but you'll find that most retailers will keep their prices as £x.99 after the change. I guess they either choose to absorb the cost or pass it on.

Comment: I understand the reasoning for it, but I still felt it dishonest. I gave an answer, though - what you do with your business is up to you. I expect most small retailers will actually just absorb this change, much as they didn't decrease prices when VAT was at 15% last year. For items that are £10, a £0.20 decrease in profit margin would probably seem favourable (with the marketing benefit of saying "we're freezing the vat") compared to upsetting regular customers.

Comment: I'm working on behalf of our client, so it's their decision ultimately. I agree with your point.